# Can elliptic curve over non-perfect field be reduced to Weierstrass form?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I have been reading 'The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves' by Silverman.

It proves that any elliptic curve defined over a **perfect field** can be reduced to Weierstrass form, [III.3.1,page 59]. The convention $k$ is perfect is mentioned at the begining of the book.

The proof uses the fact that $\bar{k}/k$ is Galois when $k$ is perfect.

Hence I don't know how to move the proof to the case $k$ is non-perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. And the result can be found in J.S.Milnes’ book, Elliptic Curves, II, theorem 2.4, page 53. And it starts with “Let $k$ be an arbitrary field,” which is exactly what I want.

It depends on the Riemann-roch theorem over arbitrary field, proved in QingLiu's book, Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curve, 7.3.2, Remark 3.33. See also 7.4.1, Corollary 4.5 which gives a closed embedding of elliptic curve into $\mathbb{P}^2_k$.